# Classification Image, Tensorflow, Accuracy stuck in 10%

Tags: image, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

i'm actually doing the CINIC-10 Classification image challenge for my IT studies.

i never had DeepLearning experience before so i learnt it with some youtube videos.

I first tried the MNIST dataset for handwritting numbers and i had a great experience from it.
My model had a 92% chance of prediction and it worked great.

now i'm Trying to classify some images and even when i use different models from Keras my training model don't go above 10% of accuracy.

here's how i proceeded :

First i'm loading my Dasasets i have a train dataset and a validation dataset.

```
# loading in the data

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
cinic_directory_train,
validation_split=0.2,
subset="training",
seed=123,
image_size=(32, 32),
batch_size=16
)

validation_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
cinic_directory_train,
validation_split=0.2,
subset="validation",
seed=123,
image_size=(32, 32),
batch_size=16  
)
```

with that i can get my clases names

```
class_names= train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

Output :
['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'\]
```

and this is my model construction :

```
model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)

])

model.compile(
optimizer='adam',  #Fonction d'optimisation
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

And when i start the train session

```
history = model.fit( 
train_ds, 
validation_data=validation_ds, 
epochs=3 
)
```

my Accuracy is stuck between 0.09 and 0.10

I even tested my friends code and i keep getting the same accuracy beside they get like 30-50% of accuracy.

I'm using google Collabs for this.

I tried all those model and i keep getting alow accuracy :

- VVG16 => 9%
- Resnet50 => 9%
- DenseNEt => 8%
- EfficientNet => 2%
- MobileNet => 9%

I can't find my problem and how to fix it!

Comment: You are missing a softmax activation on the output layer.

Comment: I already tried softmax, sigmoid nothing change

Comment: Try to have a closer look at the pixel value ranges of the images. I think `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` already does scale the pixel values to float in a range between 0 and 1. Thus you would not need `keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),` in the model.

Comment: I used the same code and started it from my Phone via google collab... i'm getting more thant 50% accuracy...

And now it's working FINE now?!

What the HECK ?

Answer (score 0):

you final layer should be

```
keras.layers.Dense(10. activation='softmax')
```